# SwiftUI: retrieving and displaying boolean literal values

Tags: boolean, swiftui

I have a data model that includes a couple of booleans. I get the following error:  "*Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Bool' conform to 'StringProtocol'*" when I try to retrieve and display the booleans. I am a total novice to SwiftUI and any help is greatly appreciated

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventRow: View {
    var event: Event

    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        return formatter
    }


    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Date: ").bold() + Text(self.dateFormatter.string(from: event.eventDate))
                Text("Details: ").bold() + Text(event.eventDetails).italic()
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)

            HStack{
                Text("Category: ").bold() + Text(event.eventCategory)
                Text("Time: ")
                    .bold()
                    + Text(event.eventDuration)
            }.font(.footnote)

            HStack{

                Text("In-House?: ").bold()
                    + Text(event.eventInHouse)
                Text("At-Nite? : ")
                    .bold()
                    + Text(event.eventNite)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Event` provided, but I assume it is for `eventInHouse` and similar, so you can use like

```swift
Text("In-House?: ").bold()
   + Text(event.eventInHouse ? "Yes" : "No")
```